# Need to get id value from json array in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

```
JSONObject test = get_details();
```

Here is my input:

```
   test = {"users": [{"id": 1, "address": "CA"}]}
   System.out.println("test : " + test);

   users = test.get("users")
   System.out.println("users : " + users);
```

output:

```
test : {"users": [{"id": 1, "address": "CA"}]}
users : [{"id": 1, "address": "CA"}]
```

I want to get the `id` value from users as below:

```
1
```

How can I get it?

Comment: 1. parse json (use org.json - http://www.json.org/javadoc/index.html?org/json/package-summary.html) 2. get your value.

Comment: Did you really mean Java, or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Users is an array. So you can try:

```
users[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**JSONObject**](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) and parse your JSON String like this:

```
String jsonMessage='{"users": [{"id": 1, "address": "CA"}]}';
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(jsonMessage);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
     JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createReader(new StringReader(scanner.nextLine())).readObject();
     System.out.println("the id is :"+jsonObject.getInt("id"));
}
```

And you can manage the `jsonObject.getInt("id")` like you want.